# Is it possible to show on the user profile whether the Flag Weight has increased or decreased?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-weight

The new [*Flag Weight*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80170/148310) is cool.

However, would it be possible to show a `+` or `-`, depending if the last change increased or decreased the weight?

This way, we could tell at a glance if our flagging is spot on or not.

Comment: Let's not.  Meta is going to buried with angst over this.

Comment: @Hans I'm not sure if I understand your comment, would you mind elaborating? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Sure**

We now **only** show the number of **helpful** flags on your profile page (visible only to you) ... this number only ever increases.

Flag weight on the other hand, is gone ... it is dead.

Comment: Is it still used internally to prioritize tags?

Comment: sort of, it is there but it has a very minor effect. We will be adjusting this as we go

Comment: I love this! Now I can actually tell when new flags I add have been acted upon, rather than just staring at a non-changing number.

Comment: [It still needs to be replaced in candidate's election listings](http://serverfault.com/election) (unless you don't want to do so during currently-running elections).

Comment: How does this impact the way that a user gets more mod flags?

Comment: So I have 24 helpful flags on my account, **but** 122 moderator attention flags when I goto my flag summary page, most of them made before flags were recorded, do all count towards the badges, in my case Marshall (I have deputy)

Comment: @waffles - I guess this is limited, but if anyone has ever participated in an election, their flag weight is still displayed on their nomination blurb. I don't know if this is intentional or not.