# Where'd my flag weight go?

Tags: support, flag-weight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight)

I'm sure this has been asked before (though I can't find it), but was flag weight suddenly removed?  My (logged in) profile page now shows only the number of helpful flags.  Clicking on this numbers brings me to my flagging history, which no longer shows flag weight.

Has flag weight finally been pulled after all the complaints about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it has. If you look at the explanations of the (formerly) flag-weight badges, they are now awarded based on helpful flag count.

Comment: Glorious!  Great change!