# Where is flag weight feature?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flag-weight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight)

Some day's back I was able to see my flag weight on my profile on stack overflow site. But now a day's there is nothing like that just a count of helpful flags.

Is this feature removed from site or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "feature" was removed because people were obsessing over their flag weight rather than concentrating what the site is about - getting great questions and answers.

It's been replaced by a simple count of how many helpful flags you've raised.

Comment: Got it, I can see the count thanks

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been removed and replaced by just count of helpful flags, as visible on your profile.

It doesn't matter what is your flag weight, but what your number of helpful flags is.

Comment: Your flag weight is still used to order the flags in the moderation queue.

Answer (score 1):

Its removed because count of all flag doesnot matter if they are wrong. It matters only if they are usefull or not so now it displays only usefull flags.