# Are flags ever automatically declined after edit

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567402/why-should-i-use-idisposable-instead-of-using-in-c/18585325#18585325) (which I think does not attempt to answer the question ([Why should I use IDisposable instead of using in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567402/why-should-i-use-idisposable-instead-of-using-in-c)). Soon after it was given [this (incredibly minor, 6 character) edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18585325/revisions), and then the flag was declined (my question is *could* these actions have been related).

The answer as it now stands:

> 1.) You should remove finalizer.
>   2.) You can have using
>   3.) You can call Dispose from try/finally block

*To me, this makes no attempt to answer the question... Granted, the entire question is probably off-topic (I also voted to close the questions as "recommending a tool or library...").*

**Will a flag ever be *automatically* declined after an edit (or must this have been an honest flag decline)?**

Related questions (but mostly older, so I'm not sure if the situation has changed):

- [Flag declined after a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105448/flag-declined-after-a-day)
- [Flag Declined after posted edited the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136242/flag-declined-after-posted-edited-the-post)
- [Indicate that a post has been edited since being flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/indicate-that-a-post-has-been-edited-since-being-flagged)
- [Flag declined after an edit. How can we fix this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116764/flag-declined-after-an-edit-how-can-we-fix-this)

Comment: Why are established users editting a question/answer that is hopelessly deficient in the first instance?

Comment: @GarryVass that edit was astonishing... I thought the worst bit was that it doesn't even make it a markdown list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags that are "not an answer" are never automatically declined or disputed by an edit. The only action that can dismiss these flags automatically is answer deletion, either directly (with the delete link), as a result of converting to comment or appending to question, as a result of question deletion, or by account destruction.

This answer comes off as handwaving to me. I didn't decline the flags, but I suppose handwaving counts as an attempt to answer the queston, if a really poor one.

Comment: Not sure I agree it's hand-wavy in an attempting to answer the question way though... (Question is about *why* not *how*, or at least that is how I interpreted it.)