# Why does my flag limit get reduced day by day?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight, declined-flags, flag-history

For the past two days I was reviewing Stack Overflow Q&A. And I came across this concept. 
The first day I was able to flag 41 posts. And after that I got  the warning that **"You can flag only 41 posts per day"**, and yesterday when I was reviewing I got the message that **"You can flag only 40 posts per day"** and today I got the message that, **"You can flag only 39 posts per day"**.

So why is there this difference in Flag Limit each day?

Comment: I think it depends upon how many mods are online--not sure.

Comment: Are your flags getting declined?

Comment: yes 1 or 2 gets declined?

Comment: @Manishearth absolutely not!!

Comment: If you believe flag was declined without valid reason please post it here and we'll see and help you understand why it was declined.

Comment: @Sha hmm.. Seem to have read a meta post on it. _shrug_

Comment: @Man this might only affect how long it takes for a flag to be reviewed - without any mods handling flags, the flag weight won't change at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

More and more of your flags are getting declined, and that's leading Stack Overflow to trust your flagging skills less. One way that's manifested is in the reduced number of flags you're allowed each day. Once upon a time, you were able to see a quantitative measure of that trust, called "flag weight", but [no more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight) (and good riddance!).

Review your recent flags (from your profile page, click the link to the right of the "*helpful flags*" label), and reflect on why they're getting declined.

Comment: so if that's the case, how will I be able to improve my flag limit? Will that keep reducing only or there are ways to increase the limit again?

Comment: AFAIK, the flag weight system is still used to prioritize flags and determine how many flags you get. But now you can't see your flag weight anymore. You probably had a very high flag weight, so a couple of declined flags will penalize you heavily.

Comment: @Andro, learn from your recent flag declines, and flag better in the future. Post here if you can point to specific instances of your flags being declined that you disagree with.

Comment: @Mystical: That is true, the flag weight *does* still exist; it's just secret now.