# How my flag limit is increasing daily?

Tags: discussion, flags, limits, helpful-flags

My flag limit is increasing day by day. I haven't noticed before how many flag I can raise. But since I am noticing it is increased a lot. In last week, I have raised above 200 helpful flags.

I have noticed to increase it from 36. Daily it is increasing by 1. Now it is reached to 40.

Is it good/ bad?
On what basis, flag limit is getting increasing daily?

Comment: How could it possibly be bad?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**How many flags do I have?**

When you start out you are alloted 10 flags per-day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per-day:

- You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
- You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts)

### A Good Thing

[The amount of flags can be reduced if you flag incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128912/why-does-my-flag-limit-get-reduced-day-by-day)

Comment: didn't know about that 100 flags per day part. thanks for that information :) +1

Comment: Interesting. This count can reach upto 100. Will it decrease at any point of time if I flag incorrectly?

Comment: that will decrease your count when it comes declined

Comment: @SomnathMuluk. I don't know they didn't mention this scenario, and I always flag correctly... `:)`

Comment: yes @gdoron, it get decrease on the declined flag, you should update your answer

Comment: @Lucifer. I don't want to write something without a source, if you find one, you can edit my answer and add it. I couldn't find any source of it.

Comment: Got one question regarding decreasing flag weight. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128912/why-does-my-flag-limit-get-reduced-day-by-day