# Moderator declined flag

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation, declined-flags, not-constructive

When I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048554/jsonserializer-serialize-static-class-of-vars). That question is not much explained, I saw the question time, it was a hour before and two people left the comment as `what you have tried`, no response from question made person.

I flagged it as `not constructive`, but after some hour he cleanly explained it, I thought to `unflag` it, but unfortunately there is no option in SO (I think so), so moderator declined my flag. Why my flag is declined? In the system of SO, is that moderator can't see the status of question when I flag it?

Comment: Do we really need new questions here on Meta for *every* flag users disagree with being declined? This is getting rather annoying, almost as much as "Why can't I ask questions anymore?"

Comment: @animuson: Shouldn't i ask this type of question here? I thought to know why my question is declained. George explained it clearly. I will be careful...

Comment: @AbdulRahman: No, you're right to ask here.  It's just that we sometimes get a lot of these kinds of questions.

Comment: @AbdulRahman: If you have a generally good track record and you get a declined flag, it's better to just let it go and be more careful. I get declined flags on occasion, but I don't go off asking about it every time I do. The bottom line is declined = the moderator disagreed. It's *only* a flag, no big deal. If you're worried about having declines on your record, you might be interested in [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141286), which would allow anyone to flag their own flags as invalid (thus always dismissing it as disputed, rather than declined).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks Robert, I won't be post unnecessary questions.

Comment: @animuson: Thanks for your link, it helps me to know new thing in SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not decline your flag, but I would have for the following reasons:

The question was not `not constructive` (read: not a good fit).  It needed more information to be answerable, which would make it `Not a Real Question`.

Not Constructive would be

> What is the best serializer to use in .NET?

Because of the analytics in use in the review queue (and other places), we've been told to be more strict about 'accepting' flags that are off base.  It used to be that a flag, even incorrect, would be marked 'helpful' if there was something off about the question.  No longer.  If you want us to take action on a question, then flag it correctly.  Blindly flagging `Not Constructive` doesn't work any longer.

Comment: I think the stricter flag checking is a good thing, but I don't remember seeing this publicized. As far as you know, has this been discussed anywhere (other than in your answer)?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation George, i am not blindly flagging at all. So far, I flagged 141 helpful flag. I will be careful in my way...

Comment: @Michael: it's always been "at the moderator's discretion", with the guideline being, dismiss as helpful if it was in anyway useful in bringing the post to a moderator's attention. This has always been somewhat problematic though, in those cases where the flag reason selected has **no** connection to the actual problems with the post - and more recently, it's caused some issues with our work on /review by creating a crapload of bad data from scatter-shot flagging.

Comment: [Relevant FAQ entry soaking here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently), since this seems to be coming up somewhat frequently again. Feel free to edit as needed.

Comment: @TinyTimPost Bugger. That's awesome work!  I wish I had thought of it.