# Request for clarification on a flag decline

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Just wondering if someone could clarify the reason as to why my flag was declined for an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645070/iis-7-host-headers-not-working/14260038#14260038) (I have added the link to the answer which has been deleted but anyone with moderator permissions on SO should be able to see the it).

[image: Flag decline reason]

I suspect that someone may have flagged the answer as spam in addition to my 'not an answer' flag as the answer was just randomly formatted text with a random comment from the person who submitted the answer under it also.

Is this the case (in which case the comment is misleading) or was there an error on my part here? :S

Comment: Your guess is probably correct. This happens when there are other flags and the best option for those is to decline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there was no error on your part, there was a spam flag on the post.

Because [the moderators are taking a literal approach to spam flags, NAA flags, and LQ flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754/140951) (and the spam flag has the highest priority out of all of these flags) and it *wasn't* obvious spam, I declined the spam flag.

Unfortunately, your NAA flag was swept up with the rest of that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I agree on it not meeting the criteria for spam seeing as there was no advertising in the answer.

Comment: @Ren No problem.