# Question flagged as offtopic - flag declined - question then closed as offtopic - flag remains listed as declined

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

In this instance when a question **is** closed for a particular reason, would it not be better to then mark any flag with the same reasoning as "helpful" even if the flag had been previously declined by another moderator?

**Edit**

I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257300/memory-issue-for-android-and-ios-device) as off topic as (other issues aside) it was more a technical question. The flag was declined but it was later closed as off topic.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ofcourse - see my edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a spam flag on the post.

Because [the moderators are taking a literal approach to spam flags, NAA flags, and LQ flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754/140951) (and the spam flag has the highest priority out of all of these flags) I had to decline the spam flag.

Unfortunately, your flag was swept up with the rest of that.  It *was* off topic, so then it was closed as such, but it *wasn't* spam, and I *had* to decline that.

Comment: Thanks, that puts the reasoning behind the decline into context.

Comment: @DMK [This isn't the first time that I've had to do this today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163242/140951); apparently, there are some people who don't know how to use the spam/offensive flag (and we can't see who's sending them, either).