# Should I raise flags for issues the community can handle, even if mods will likely mark as helpful?

Tags: discussion, flags

on SO I have 7k reputation currently, which is enough to close questions but not enough to delete questions with downvotes.  (I don't know the exact logic for this, but a 10k+ user once explained to me and I recall 10k+ users can vote to delete questions with sufficient downvotes.)

Flagging is incentivized.  There are a silver and a gold badge for raising helpful flags.  Moderators will mark flags as helpful or unhelpful which I use as feedback much like a lab rat gets an electric shock or cheese.  However, something that has confused me is the "very low quality" answers that I flag as probably needing to be deleted *don't* need moderator attention - they need 10k+ user attention.

Similarly I had the exact same feelings at < 3k with flagging to close questions.  Doesn't need moderator attention, but usually marked as helpful.

So I see a conflict between "let the community moderate, save moderators as human exception handlers" with "raise flags that will be marked as helpful."  What gives?

Comment: In all likelihood some of your helpful flags have been handled entirely by 10k users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags aren't reviewed by Moderators only. 10k+ users can also review a part of the flag queue (I thought they only can't review the 'other' flag option).

So my answer will be: Yes, flag those! Someone, a mod or a 10k+ user, will review it and determine if it needs to get deleted or not.

Comment: 10kers also don't see Spam or Offensive flags :).

Answer (score 1):

All flags except the custom mod flags and spam/offensive flags are seen by 10k users, and they help handle them. See https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools.

So, continue flagging these, you're doing the right thing. Be careful about [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently), though.

Also, note that flagging to close once you have >3k will have your flag converted to a vote to close

Comment: @JoshCaswell: NAA as well.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.