# Why was this deleted 'first answer' in the first post review queue today?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, deleted-answers, review-audits

I just picked a 'first answer' to review (https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1875090), and I'm puzzled.  When I go to the question ([How to correctly export Weight and Bias value of Backpropagation neural network into another programming language (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229224/how-to-correctly-export-weight-and-bias-value-of-backpropagation-neural-network)), the 'answer' was deleted on 24th March 2013.  Why am I asked to review it on 7th April 2013?

[image: tail end of deleted 'answer']

I think this is a potential bug in the first post review queue queueing algorithm.

Comment: It's just a review audit.

Comment: Oh — I suppose it could be a review audit.  Not a very sensible one, though...well, not what I'd expect to be required to review.  Oh well!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Moderators [have become quite strict](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently) when it comes to processing quality related flags to ensure these audits aren't fed incorrectly, but a few oddballs that are indecipherable without the full context of other answers in addition to the question do occasionally still creep in. The flags / deletion make sense, but only from a higher vantage point than review. If ever unsure, just skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This type of reviews are called as [review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info).

From [review audits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/187824):

> **First Posts** and **Late Answers** - The test presents a reviewer with a post that was previously removed by a moderator and known to be of extremely poor quality (flagged as spam, not an answer or very low quality).