# My flagging is not deemed helpful

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, flag-history, disputed-flags

I am flagging posts on SO which do not appear to be helpful to the site. If the flag i raise is helpful then why is my flag marked as disputed/not-helpful.

Most of the questions I have flagged have been put on hold. How does this happen?

Check the following screen shot:

> [image: Image LINK]

Comment: Did you read the description of "very low quality"?

Comment: Yes. N most of these questions are. Am i marking them wrong? do i mark these questions in any other way?

Comment: Are the questions you flagged so badly written that they have to be outright deleted? Or should they just be closed/put on hold?

Comment: Thanks gnat for adding the image. I dont have enough rep to post one

Comment: I dont think that its a duplicate of what you posted gnat. I  just wanted to know if im marking the flags wrongly.

Comment: Am I missing something here? One cannot flag questions as *very low quality* by default. Have you entered "very low quality" manually after clicking *it needs ♦ moderator attention*?

Comment: Ok, I did a little self research and turns out i was flagging the questions incorrectly. 
There is a little more effort required in flagging than i thought. 

So although my intentions were clear my execution was not. I was marking all the questions as very low quality which is a very broad classification. The correct flagging would be off-topic / not sure what you are asking. 

Il keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @slhck, very low quality is the default option you get when you flag a  post

Comment: Seems you found your answer. The funny thing is, I do not see the *very low quality* option when flagging questions at all.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/byOBB.png

Comment: @slhck: that option's rep-sensitive I think. Try on a site where you don't have much rep.

Comment: @Mat Indeed. Thank you. That just adds to my confusion about why we have this flag in the first place. Oh well.

Comment: See also: [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently)

Comment: @slhck: it also shows up for high-rep users on non-closed but downvoted questions (probably some threshold) e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194057/why-declined-flag-on-a-offensive-username - it's the "please delete this, it's hopeless" flag.