# Not An Answer Flag Dispute

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Yesterday I flagged [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18459081) as Not An Answer and the flag was declined.

<strike>The answer is from the person who originally asked the question and appears to be a response to a comment on the question.</strike>

The answer is from a person with the same name as the original poster (sockpuppet?, I'll flag this separately) and appears to be a response to a comment on the question.

Comment:

> Perhaps the label's font simply isn't available and therefore it creates a blank, opaque texture? What font are the labels using? Try changing the fontName parameter to "Arial" or "Courier" for fixed-width.

Answer:

> The Label's font is Helvetica which is available by default. It can not be a problem, because some messages appear right some not.

What can I do now to further dispute the "answer"?

Comment: I think the mod who handled the flag missed that the OP created a *new* account to post that 'answer'.

Comment: IMO, it looks like an answer. I would have flagged it as other with an explanation that the user created a second account, and then posted an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: I had until I just had another look. I was busy editing this question as you posted that comment.

Comment: @bluefeet, maybe it just needs a little more knowledge of the libraries involved, but the code posted doesn't answer the question. It clarifies the question :P

Comment: @JamesWebster But not an answer is typically other questions being posted as answers, comments, thanks responses, etc.  If I was looking at that it looks like it was an answer.  I don't think flagging it as _not an answer_ was the appropriate flag.

Comment: Fair enough, I see where the dispute on the flag came from now. I was only viewing it as an amendment especially with the user answering it having the same user name

Comment: @JamesWebster I totally get that but that is what the "other" flag category is used for. :)

Comment: To me, it looks like Mikka (OP) was trying to clarify. The content added in the answer looks like what he has tried but doesn't work. Also the answer seemed to be addressing the request for clarification by [LearnCoco2D's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445796/cocos2d-cclabelttf-diplays-solid-rectangle/18459081#comment27119407_18445796) on that question.

Comment: @OldCheckmark, this is how I saw it? Are we just wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I declined that flag.

At first glance, I read a little of the question and the answer and mistakenly thought the answer was an attempt to help with part of the problem. Because the user had created a second account to add clarifying information, it didn't show up in the moderator panel as an answer by the question's owner. I guess I didn't bother to read the comments after thinking it was a viable answer.

In general, "not an answer" flags should come on material that requires no additional explanation as to why it should be deleted. These include follow-on questions, gibberish, and clear attempts by people to comment on the question or other answers. As bluefeet suggests, if it isn't immediately obvious why we should summarily delete the answer, help us out with an "other" flag and drop in a description like you did just now. I know I personally find "other" flags a lot easier to act on, because we can better see what you did.

We can get dozens of bad "not an answer" flags some days, and [we're being a little stricter with those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently) given their new role as audit cases, so that can bias us towards declining flags like this.

I corrected my mistake and removed the answer in response to your second flag. Again, sorry for not catching that this was a follow-on comment.

Comment: And what about possible sock puppet?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - So far, this simply looks like a case of losing one login and creating a new one to post a follow-on, since they couldn't comment any more. The new account can't vote for the old one, and I see no other shenanigans so far.

Comment: Should we guide the user to merge the accounts then?

Answer (score 8):

I think flagging that answer as "not an answer" was not the correct flag and I can see why it was declined.

The answer looks like an answer.  It is not up to the mods to judge whether or not an answer is technically accurate. I know nothing about iphone development but on first glance this looks like an attempt to answer the question by posting code to create `ccLabelTTFs`.

This answer doesn't fit the typically "not an answer" candidate. The user didn't post a *I have the same question, did you solve it?*  There is no *thanks this works*. Based on that it doesn't seem to fit as not an answer so I wouldn't have flagged this an not an answer.

I personally would have used the "other" flag and stated in the explanation 2 things - that it looks like the original user created a second account and then used the second account to post an answer with code clarification instead of editing the original question.