# Disputed spam flag

Tags: discussion, spam, disputed-flags

I flagged an answer as spam (relevant question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513790/how-to-convert-cmt-files-to-jpg-or-png/22513975#22513975) and the flag was disputed. As far as I can see, the answer basically boils down to "You can buy this software here [link] and it'll do what you need.

In addition to this, a real answer to the question would be rather lengthly (through my own research, which I posted as a comment to the question) and it's probable that no answer would be able to completely answer the question as is.

I do understand that it means a 10k user disagreed with my flag, but I'm curious as to why. Is this not spam?

Comment: I wouldn't call that spam. That just seems to be a genuine attempt at an answer by a user not affiliated with the product. That it's a product or library doesn't make it spam. Perhaps it's not a great answer, but I would have disputed the flag as well.

Comment: Just a note: 10k users can't see spam/offensive flags in the queue. They're only marked as disputed if a moderator clears them off a post rather than flat-out declining the flag.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Answer (score 13):

It's an attempt to answer the question.  It's not like it's advertising a product that won't solve the exact problem requested.

It's also not being posted on a whole bunch of questions, as would also be an indication of spam.

It's (arguably) a low quality answer in that it doesn't go into detail, or explain how to use the product to solve the problem, which can be justification for downvoting, if you feel that that is warranted.

It's not universally prohibited to suggest the use of a commercial product in solving a problem, as you seem to be implying.

Comment: Also, note that accepted spam flags can have serious penalties and will feed into the review queue as audits, so we tend to [take those a little more seriously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently).

Comment: So spam flag is really only appropriate for a pattern of posts that look like probable advertisements? I guess I just misunderstood because it really is just "buy this and you get it done". I also just went over http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts and didn't realize spam flags had such a negative consequence

Comment: The kind of spam flag that really chaps my ass is the one that is cast on a post using "spam" as a synonym for "nonsense" (having nothing to do with unsolicited commercial advertisement).

Comment: @jdphenix I guess you haven't seen the posts that answer software development questions with links for Gucci purses or watching the football games online? **Those** are spam. Completely unrelated to the topic and no chance of being helpful to anyone either.