# Failed a questionable audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4411272) audit earlier. I marked it as no action needed because as an answer I thought it was okay. I didn't see the question because it said the question was deleted (there was no title or anything). Now that I can see the question that was asked, I think it would still be a valid answer.

Comment: What makes you think that the audit was questionable?  The answer isn't clearly an answer; it ought to be a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, devnull. It would depend on the question asked.

Comment: The question was for some html code to display some random images and the poster was answering and said it can't be done on pure HTML, you will need to use JS, JQuery etc. I would definitely view that as an answer more than a comment

Comment: @Pëkka I'm not sure if the question deserved an answer to begin with.  A question that isn't clear will probably attract vague answers.

Comment: Based on Howlin's description of the question, this looks like an answer. Not a great one but one nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

That's an interesting case. It had two "not an answer" flags on it (which I personally would have declined), but those flags were automatically marked helpful by the system when the asker deleted their own question, taking the answer with it.

Moderators are [usually a little more strict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently) with flags like that for just this reason, that they get used as audit cases. Perhaps answers deleted when the question is removed could be excluded from being used as audits to prevent this.

This is a pretty rare case, though, because I'm not sure I've seen this before.

Comment: I'd personally rather see flags like this dismissed as disputed. Yeah, it's kind of pointless to make a moderator come look at an answer on a deleted question, but that doesn't mean those flags were helpful and I don't like that a post's author can dismiss them as such.

Comment: Need fix it, not direct(cascade) answers removing should not mark its flag... seems like a bug...