# Should the "flag-weights" tag be renamed to the "helpful-flags"?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, flag-weight, helpful-flags

As Waffles wrote @ https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119714/143601:

> We now **only** show the number of **helpful** flags on your profile
>   page (visible only to you) ... this number only ever increases.
>
> Flag weight on the other hand, is gone ... it is dead.

Should we rename the existing [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) tag to the [helpful-flags](/questions/tagged/helpful-flags)? And/or create a synonym? Or just leave it as is (for historical purposes, for example)?

*Just in case… No personal interest here as I'd rather prefer [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) -> [helpful-flags](/questions/tagged/helpful-flags) rename, than Taxonomist badge for the latter.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. They're different mechanisms and much of the discussion about flag weight won't apply to a simple helpful flag counter.

Retag what makes sense and close/delete/comment/etc. on the rest.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.