# What determines the number of flags I get after the removal of flag weight?

Tags: support, flags, flag-weight

The flag weight feature has been [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight).  Now what determines the number of flags I get each day?

Comment: I have 38 inform moderator flags, 33 spam/not welcome flags, and 50 doesn't belong here flags, with 128 helpful flags; and 11 flags with 1 helpful flag.

Comment: Here are [the old rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117).  Note that the number of flags you get is somewhat based on reputation.

Comment: At this time on Super User, I get 40 moderator attention flags and 35 spam/offensive and comment flags per day, with 308 helpful flags on my record.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint: Flag weight is still there, it's just not shown.

Comment: :o waffles lied! [He said it was dead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119714/141525)!

Comment: Will it be removed from the internals or remain in the system?  Is this a transitional period?

Comment: See the comments under [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119716/50049) by @Waffles. It's still being used as intended (at least as far as ordering our queue goes), it's just not being shown anymore.

Comment: this tiny answer here is what I have been trying to find out for over a month!! THANK YOU .. Please go and be amazed by some hand drawn unicorns http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192102/flagging-history-summary