# We need a new way to calculate the number of flags per day

Tags: discussion, flags, limits

Flag weight is [no longer visible in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight), but is [still used internally to calculate the number of flags per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120117/160017).  We need a new way to calculate the number of flags each user gets per day.  Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Given that this suggestion was not a good one, perhaps we should rewrite the FAQs to reflect the fact that a hidden flag weight value is used to calculate the number of flags per day?

Comment: Why do we need a new way of calculating that?

Comment: I don't think anything needs to be changed at all.

Comment: I wonder how @BoltClock feels about this! ;)

Comment: @Mat: Flags per day should not be based on stats not visible to normal users.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Don't ask.

Comment: @DragonLord: why not?

Comment: Rewarding users flagging correctly is important, and we should not base this reward on invisible values but on stats they can see.  Besides, because flag weight increases sub-linearly beyond 500, a bad flag can have a much greater impact on the flag weight than a large number of good flags, diminishing one reward of raising good flags and creating a unnecessary risk of discouraging users with strong flagging records.

Comment: Flag weight was made invisible because making it visible caused very specific problems: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106614/remove-flag-weight-and-flag-validity-already Any suggestion to make any flag weight or similar number visible must address these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system calculates the number of flags you're provided internally.  As long as you flag correctly, the number of flags you are allotted increases.  If you flag badly, that number decreases.

The user can find out how many flags they have available by starting to flag a post - they will see how many flags they have left for that day.

This feature request fails to show how stack overflow will be improved (either in better posts, better flagging, etc) by showing the calculation itself.

If you can demonstrate how this feature would improve stack overflow, then you might gain some traction, but the effort that would be applied to making this more transparent is better spent on other features that would actually improve Stack Overflow.

If anything, this is a navel gazing feature.

[image: Flagging dialogue box showing 29 inform moderator flags remaining]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DragonLord I've clarified my statement.