# How many flags does a user have per day?

Tags: support, flags

How is the amount of flags per day calculated, or why was my amount of flags decreased by 1?

I am flagging quite a lot and I know that I got an additional flag from time to time. Last week I had 51 moderator attention flags per day with about 2350 helpful flags and 15 declined flags.

Then another one was declined and my flags decreased to 50 per day.

There is an "old" question: [Are the new moderator flag limits sufficiently high?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high), but its answer is still "flag weight" based and seems outdated. Or is the flag weight still calculated in the background?

It is not that important, but I love to have the flags increased and it is a bit disappointing when one is removed. So what are the rules regarding the number of flags one can raise?

Comment: Flag weight is still used in the background. If you had max flag weight previously, you need almost 100 helpful flags (in a row) to get the last bonus flag back.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[As of June 25, 2013, flag weight appears to have been dropped entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890) in favor of straight net count.

- default 10 per day
- one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
- one bonus flag for every 10 net helpful flags (helpful - declined)
- maximum 100

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120117), flag weight is still used to determine the number of flags you get, it just isn't shown to anyone (moderator or otherwise).

Therefore, the calculation in the thread you linked should still hold:

> - default 10 per day
> - one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
> - one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default
> - maximum 100

Answer (score 7):

**How many flags do I have?**

When you start out you are alloted 10 flags per-day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per-day:

- You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
- You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.

when your flags get declined, it deducts your daily flag count limit. After reaching a certain level the flag count increment become slow ( bonus flag ) but when no of your flags get declined your flag count decreases faster.

[Original Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: Thats the part I already know, it is also described in the question I linked. I would be interested in more details on the calculation.

Comment: well i dont think the perfect calculation is opened. It's system designed like that way.

Comment: The calculation is indeed public. Though now that flag weight is hidden, it's slightly more difficult to calculate.

Comment: Isn't flag weight just number of helpful flags times 10? I thought I saw this somewhere but cannot find it. In other words, it's not really dead, just hidden, and it's still used in calculations on things like number of flags, if memory serves.

Comment: @jmort253: There was a great graph explaining the non-linear behavior of flag weight [in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87732/total-10-00-flag-weight-for-10-good-flags-but-10-flag-weight-for-1-bad-flag/91234#91234). Unfortunately, the thread has since been deleted, so only users with 10k+ rep can see it.