# Something weird with moderator flags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

When I tried to flag a question for moderator attention, even though I just flag once, it took away two of my flags. At first, it said that I have 11 flags, but when I flagged the question, it said I have 9 flags, so why did it take away two flags?

Comment: I just tested on this question (sorry mods), and it only took away one vote for me. What does your flagging history show (click "Helpful flags" on your profile)?.. does it show only one vote or two?

Comment: @hammar: That's almost certainly what it is.  I declined the OP's last moderator flag.

Comment: @hammar: It is definitely still used to determine how many flags you get. [See here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149670)

Comment: @Robert looks like this should be status-bydesign then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number of flags you have per day [depends on your net helpful flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149670), which is the number of your flags that were marked helpful minus the number that were marked declined.

What likely happened here (as confirmed by Robert Harvey in a comment) is that while you were flagging, a moderator declined one of your other flags, pushing your net helpful flags down enough for you to lose a flag.