# Is it OK to mass flag if they would be helpful flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

I'm currently part of Android Stack Exchange, and there are tons of things to flag there. APK building help, app recommendations, phone suggestions - and even spam. So many, I have almost used all my daily flags.

While flagging helps the community, it feels kind of wrong to use half my flags in the short span of a few minutes - even if they are helpful.

Is this OK? Or would it be better to do something else (e.g.: waiting to send more flags)?

Comment: This might be better asked on Android's own meta, but in general, flagging all the way up to your limit (which can be as high as 100/day!) is helpful for the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" with using a lot of flags in a short period of time, provided you are acting in good faith. However, if you feel you are frequently raising an excessive number of flags, you can consider a number of options:

- **Flag the post instead of a chain of obsolete comments**: See [Monica's answer here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4488/3192) to my question on another site.

  > The best approach is to **flag the post** and explain what's going on. Obsolete flags can be harder to evaluate (there's no way to tell us why you think it's obsolete), so a custom flag is better in a case like that.

  Moderators usually have to see the complete post (and conversation in comments) anyway to decide if the comment is obsolete.
- **Start a discussion on site meta**: There's the possibility of a bigger problem on the site if you are *frequently* coming close to your flag quota. Perhaps other users (including moderators) have also noticed it privately. Drawing community attention publicly might help address (or at least identify) the *actual* problem.
- **Engage with users in the site chat room to fix the problems**: If your site chat room is quite active and your regular users frequently hang out there, you could start a discussion there to fix the problem instead of (or before) flagging it. For example, you can discuss how a "low quality" question can be edited into a better shape, and perhaps avoid flagging altogether.

The only downside to this is you will have to wait longer to get the Deputy and Marshall badges. :-) However, that's only if you are into that sort of thing. In my opinion, badge hunting should not be the focus of participation, and contributing in more positive ways would be appreciated more.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, as long as you use the right type of flags and flag only things that are flag-worthy, there's nothing wrong at all with this. It would be great if you'd reach the [3000 reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) necessary on Android Stack Exchange to *vote* to close instead of flagging for closure. Note that for every 10 net helpful flags you'll get [another flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149659/295232) per day, so the risk of running out of flags will be lower, given time.

Most of your flags end up in the [review queues](https://android.stackexchange.com/review), specifically the Low Quality Posts and Close Votes, and while there are some items in them right now, they don't have astronomical levels like the First Posts queue (which you can't help). If they ever do, consider prioritizing your flags towards the most problematic and recent posts.