# Raising disputed flags more than helpful flags on questions and answers

Tags: support, flags

If I am raising flags on questions and answers,
On flag-summary page it shows me something like this:

[image: Flag Summary]

Will it affect my "profile reputation" or "cause me to delete my profile permanently" if I have large number of disputed flags than deemed helpful?

Comment: While it is true that mod flags are taken seriously... it's not so drastic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disputed flags don't have any impact on your reputation, nor will they cause your profile to be deleted or changed in any way.  Disputed flags don't even have an impact on your ability to flag.  Helpful flags will increase the number of flags you get each day, and declined flags will decrease them, but disputed flags are neutral so they don't change your status at all.

Comment: thanks Bill, thats a relief.

Comment: I'm curious, how do helpful flags increase the number of flags you get each day?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure about the exact numbers, but as you submit helpful flags, the number of flags you're allowed to submit each day will go up.  I think it starts at 10 per day, but if you submit hundreds of helpful flags you'll be able to flag up to 50 posts per day.

Comment: OK thanks, I use to use them more with the old review queues, and have actually used them up a couple of times. With the new review queues I hardly use them.

Comment: @Jack the limit is 100, for the details, look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117).

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the link, it seems that its a bit outdated (For starters it looks like your flag weight is no longer displayed).

Comment: @Jack Not displayed anymore, but [still there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120117/177145).