# How is flag limit calculated now that flag weight is dead?

Tags: discussion, flags, helpful-flags

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80117/178687) says we get 'one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default'. Now that flag weight [appears to be dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119714/178687) and "helpful flags" is king, how are the daily flag limits calculated?

The [FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) just says "You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.". I'm hoping for a bit more detail than that.

Answer (score 4):

Flag weight is not dead. It is simply no longer shown, but is still calculated and stored in the backend, much like accept rate.

Additional bonus flags are granted by flag weight and one per every 2000 reputation you make.

Comment: ["Flag weight ... is dead."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82239/is-it-possible-to-show-on-the-user-profile-whether-the-flag-weight-has-increased/119714#119714) ?

Comment: @nneonneo That answer has incorrect information. Jeff himself says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120117/187954) that flag weight is still there, but simply not shown.

Comment: Gah, I missed that duplicate. The comments under Waffles' post weren't clear enough to me, apparently.